# do std::function and std::bind do dynamic memory allocation?

Tags: c++

If I do this :-

```
class Thing  
{
    ...
    void function (const std::string& message);
};

std::list<std::function<void()>> work;
```

and in some member of "Thing"

```
work.push_back(std::bind(&Thing::function, this, "Hello"));
```

Does either the call to std::bind or the use of std::function<> cause any dynamic memory allocation using new or otherwise? Or is all the storage allocated at compile time? If the standard doesn't say anything, what about in visual studio 2012 as my program will only need to build on there, and for efficiency I probably need to avoid dynamic memory allocations in the place where I am thinking of using this mechanism.

Comment: "for efficiency I probably" You shouldn't make assumptions about efficiency like that.

Comment: Using `std::list` will cause a memory allocation each time you add an item to the list.

Comment: Ahahahahahaha avoiding dynamic allocations while using std::list

Comment: Hehe true. Oops. The code actually uses a custom data structure, I simplified it for posting here and obviously a list is not appropriate.

Comment: Good old "efficiency". Does the profiling you've done so far show this particular chunk of code to be a performance bottleneck or memory hog?

Comment: @kbok I'm not making assumptions, it's gathering data based on experience. I have an inner loop of a hobby game I'm working on that's doing this 60 times a second, and I've found in the past that doing lots of small memory allocations in that inner loop leads to heap fragmentation fairly rapidly. I wanted this information to see if that was something i should consider, not to avoid outright.

Comment: @Rook sometimes you don't need profiling, but you do need some basic understanding. For example I wouldn't use a std::vector if I knew I wanted to always insert items at the beginning, I'd use a list. I wouldn't need to profile to tell me that was a better idea. Similarly here, I think that *if* these do dynamic memory allocation then they are probably not the appropriate choice for me in this situation. I do entirely get your point though

Comment: There was an interesting comment on SO recently on the relative efficiencies of `std::vector` vs `list` or `deque`. The conclusions were quite counter-intuitive! I should have noted its location...

Comment: @J99 Whereas I generally share your opinion, in fact the good old `std::vector` vs `std::list` discussion is a case where profiling might tell you something you wouldn't expect when just *"basically understanding"* the big-O of their insertion algorithms (for pretty much the same reason you try to avoid dynamic memory allocation here).

Comment: Indeed. Ok. well anyway, the point is to educate myself on how this works so I can come up with a good design knowing the issues. I don't think anyone can argue that that's a bad thing :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard doesn't specify, but in general it's easy to see that `std::function` must allocate memory at least in some cases:

```
struct huge { char c[10000]; };
void foo(const huge &);
std::function<void()>{std::bind(foo, huge{})};
```

On the other hand it's possible for it to avoid allocation in at least some cases by siting its function object inside a preallocated buffer inside the `function` object's footprint; obviously there is a tradeoff as this could make other uses take more stack memory.  A good implementation would be able to avoid memory allocation when storing a raw function pointer in a `function` object, and possibly also for a `mem_fn`, but it's less likely that it'd do so for a `bind`.

For example, libstdc++ (g++) inlines (functor) object pointers, function pointers, and (non-virtual) member function pointers, as well as anything else that'd fit in the same footprint, e.g. stateless functors ([`union _Nocopy_types`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a00297_source.html#l01652)).

If you can, by inverting your control flow to accept templated functor objects instead of `function` you can avoid any extra memory allocation:

```
template<typename F>
void my_algorithm(const F &);
my_algorithm(std::bind(foo, huge{}));
```

Answer (score 8):

I just did some research on this for the case of g++.

When it comes to std::function and dynamic memory allocation there are two key points.

1. std::function can store objects of arbitrary size, this means it *must* perform dynamic memory allocation in some cases.
2. there are certain types for which std::function is guaranteed not to throw exceptions. This implies that there are certain types it *must* store without dynamic memory allocation.

The implementation of std::function in gccs libstd+++ will store without dynamic memory allocation other things with size/alignment requirements less than or equal to the size/alignment requirements of the things it must store.

The largest thing it must store without dynamic memory allocation is a pointer to member function. On compilers based on the "itanium c++ ABI"* [this is twice the size of a normal pointer](http://lazarenko.me/wide-pointers/). So you can store anything up to two pointers in size in a std::function in g++ without triggering dynamic memory allocation.

As far as I can tell std::bind just concatenates stuff together into an object, so binding anything to a member function will result in an object that is at least three pointers in size. Assigning this object to a std::function will result in dynamic memory allocation.

A better option is to use a lambda. This refers to the member function statically, giving you space to capture up to two pointers without triggering dynamic memory allocation.

To demonstrate I wrote some test code loosely based on yours. I got rid of the string and list and used a const char * (to avoid std::string related memory allocations) and placement new (this code was only intended to be built, not to be run) instead  and fed it into godbolt.

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class Thing  
{
    void foo();
    void bar();
    void function (const char * message);
};

char baz[1024];

void Thing::foo() {
    new (baz) std::function<void()>(std::bind(&Thing::function, this, "Hello"));
}


void Thing::bar() {
    const char * s = "Hello";
    new (baz) std::function<void()>([this,s](){function(s);});
}
```

The results were.

```
Thing::foo():
        mov     r3, #0
        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
        ldr     r4, .L34
        mov     r6, r0
        sub     sp, sp, #16
        mov     r0, #16
        str     r3, [r4, #8]
        bl      operator new(unsigned int)
        ldr     r2, .L34+4
        mov     r1, #0
        mov     r3, r0
        str     r2, [sp]
        mov     r2, sp
        ldr     r5, .L34+8
        ldr     lr, .L34+12
        ldr     ip, .L34+16
        str     r1, [sp, #4]
        str     r6, [r0, #12]
        str     r0, [r4]
        str     r5, [r3, #8]
        ldm     r2, {r0, r1}
        str     lr, [r4, #12]
        stm     r3, {r0, r1}
        str     ip, [r4, #8]
        add     sp, sp, #16
        pop     {r4, r5, r6, pc}
        ldr     r3, [r4, #8]
        cmp     r3, #0
        beq     .L27
        ldr     r1, .L34
        mov     r2, #3
        mov     r0, r1
        blx     r3
.L27:
        bl      __cxa_end_cleanup
.L34:
        .word   .LANCHOR1
        .word   Thing::function(char const*)
        .word   .LC0
        .word   std::_Function_handler<void (), std::_Bind<void (Thing::*(Thing*,     char const*))(char const*)> >::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&)
        .word   std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<std::_Bind<void (Thing::*(Thing*, char const*))(char const*)> >::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Any_data const&, std::_Manager_operation)
Thing::bar():
            ldr     r2, .L38
            sub     sp, sp, #8
            stm     sp, {r0, r2}
            add     r2, sp, #8
            ldr     r3, .L38+4
            ldmdb   r2, {r0, r1}
            ldr     ip, .L38+8
            ldr     r2, .L38+12
            stm     r3, {r0, r1}
            str     ip, [r3, #12]
            str     r2, [r3, #8]
            add     sp, sp, #8
            bx      lr
    .L38:
            .word   .LC0
            .word   .LANCHOR1
            .word   std::_Function_handler<void (), Thing::bar()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&)
            .word   std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<Thing::bar()::{lambda()#1}>::_M_manager(std::_Any_data&, std::_Function_base::_Base_manager<Thing::bar()::{lambda()#1}> const&, std::_Manager_operation)
```

We can clearly see there is memory allocation in the bind case, but not in the lambda case.

* Which despite the name is used by g++ and clang++ across many different architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this. I guess, as ecatmur suggests, it depends on the implementation of std for that platform. For similar problems I've had good success using this implementation from code project. It supports a good number of platforms. Very well documented and no dynamic memory allocation.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

General purpose dynamic memory allocation at runtime in games or simulation should be avoided. The problem is not always fragmentation or a large bottleneck (both valid reasons to avoid) but also the fact that the amount of time is often non-deterministic. A more domain specific memory allocation strategy such as 'pooling' or 'framing' would be advantageous here.

http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html